# How to use VSTS Loadtest Goal based load pattern to achieve a constant test per second

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, stress-testing, load-testing

I am using Visual Studio TS Load Test for running WebTest (one client/controls hitting one server). How can I configure goal based load pattern to achieve a constant test / second?

I tried to use the counter 'Tests/Sec' under 'LoadTest:Test' but it does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently tested against the Tests / Sec, and I've confirmed it working.

For the settings on the Goal Based Load Pattern, I used:

```
Category: LoadTest:Test
Counter: Tests/Sec
Instance: _Total
```

When the load test starts, verify it doesn't show an error re: not being able to access that Performance Counter.

Tests I ran for my own needs:

- Set **Initial User Load** quite low (10), and gave it 5 minutes to see if
  it would reach the target **Tests / Sec** target, and stabilise. In my case, it stabilised after about 1 minute 40.
- Set the **Maximum User Count [Increment|Decrement]** to 50. Turns out the
  user load would yo-yo up and down quite heavily, as it would keep
  trying to play catch-up. (As the tests took 10-20 seconds each)
- Set the **Initial User Load** quite close to the 'answer' from test 1,
  and watched it make small but constant adjustments to the user
  volume.

*Note*: When watching the stats, watch the value under *"Last"*. I believe the *"Average"* is averaged over a relatively long period, and may appear out of step with the target.

Comment: Is there any list of possible categories? It's not like it's an intelligent system that can recognize what you meant by `Category: Tests`

Comment: @overflew Is there a way to have a goal of tests initiated (rather than tests completed)? I have long running tests (~4min) so the heuristic goes nuts thinking that tests/sec is 0 for 4 minutes, and then suddenly climbs through the roof as all of the backlog starts coming through.